# Multiple runners on single host running job with the same id on PR overwrites status

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow, pull-request

I have 2 self hosted runners - ‘runner’ & ‘runner-resource-free’ on 1 machine. I have 2 labels ‘Run UI tests’ and ‘Skip UI tests’. Jobs which start based on label use the same job id which is ‘pr_ui_tests_check’ and this job is marked as required in branch protection rules.

pr_check_skip_ui_tests.yaml

```
name: Skip UI tests on pull request`
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ labeled, synchronize ]

jobs:
  pr_ui_tests_check:
    if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'Skip UI tests')
    runs-on: runner-resource-free
    timeout-minutes: 10

    concurrency:
      group: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
      cancel-in-progress: true

    steps:
      - name: Skip tests
        run: echo "Tests skipped"
```

pr_check_run_ui_tests.yaml

```
name: Run UI tests on pull request
on:
pull_request:
types: [ labeled, synchronize ]

jobs:
pr_ui_tests_check:
if: contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, ‘Run UI tests’)
runs-on: runner
timeout-minutes: 150

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}

  - name: Run UI tests
    uses: ./.github/actions/run-ui-tests
```

When I run UI tests on pull request #1 using label 'Run UI tests' they start okay. But when I add label 'Skip UI tests' on pull request #2 and this job finishes it overwrites pull request #1 and marks 'pr_ui_tests_check' as  success due to skip in another pull request. How can I avoid that?